# Repeat image along circle

Tags: imagemagick, magick++

How can I repeat an image along a circle? Note that it should also get distorted a bit. What I'm trying to get to is this: I've been working on a POV LED design that takes an image and flashes it along a string of LEDs while the whole thing is spinning. When you look at the display, the image is distorted a little bit, squished in along the inner part of the circle and stretched a bit on the outer. I want to recreate that.

The red circle is for reference only and will always be the same size. I will probably leave it in the resulting composite as well. How often the image gets repeated along the circle path should be adjustable based on the actual width of the original image (and whether I'm adding a break between each copy.) For example, there are images that tile right next to each other, no break, and others that will need a break. So I need a way to define that.

With the yellow diagonal lines, I don't want a break between the image as it repeats. I left the white edges on the top one to show how it's distorted.

How can I accomplish this using Magick++? Ultimately I will take the code and incorporate it into a much large application that used Magick++ to manipulate the images that the user imports for the POV LED display.

Thanks!

[image: Repeating Image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out. So here's the snippet of code that I am now working with:

```cpp
Magick::Image srcImage;
srcImage.read("001.png");
srcImage.resize("x100");      // I want images at least 100 pixels high
Magick::Color color(0, 0, 0); // images should always be on a black background

// to add space beween a repeating image, add a value to .columns()
// for example:
// srcImage.extent(Magick::Geometry(srcImage.columns() + 10, 100), color);
// will add 10 pixels of space or padding after each image repeat
srcImage.extent(Magick::Geometry(srcImage.columns(), 100), color);

// preprocess
// .columns() is multiplied by the amount of times the image repeats in the circle
// for example, this repeats the image 8 times:
// srcImage.size(Magick::Geometry(srcImage.columns() * 8, 100));
srcImage.size(Magick::Geometry(srcImage.columns() * 8, 100));
srcImage.virtualPixelMethod(Magick::HorizontalTileEdgeVirtualPixelMethod);
const double tileArgs[1] = {0};
srcImage.distort(Magick::ScaleRotateTranslateDistortion, 1, tileArgs, Magick::MagickTrue);

// distort
srcImage.virtualPixelMethod(Magick::BlackVirtualPixelMethod);
const double arcArgs[4] = {360, 0, 98, 30};
srcImage.distort(Magick::ArcDistortion, 4, arcArgs, Magick::MagickTrue);
srcImage.write("001-out.png");
```

Comment: Looks good! You should +1 my answer, but accept your own answer instead of mine. This will help future readers identify which solution resolved your original question.

Comment: Hrm, I'm ending up with a single black pixel line at the bottom of the circle. It looks like where the edges end up meeting after the arc distortion. Any ideas?

Could it be because of previous manipulations? When I first read in an image, I check whether its height is over a certain threshold. If so, I will resize it to match a specific height. Then I will extent it and finally do the arc distortion. Could one of the edges end up with a fuzzy black pixel column which then gets more pronounced after the distortion?

Comment: Any pixel blemishes can be exaggerated during distortion. They usually need to be fixed in the source image during preprocessing. Checkout the articles @ http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/misc/, especially [Virtual Pixels](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/misc/#virtual) section. In my answer, I hinted at [bleeding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bleed_%28printing%29), which would mean to extend the image past the desired edge, apply distortion, and then trim with a mask. For portability across viewers, I usually keep the bleed in the finial image, and adjust the viewport at time of display.

Comment: Right, I know the images don't have an artifact along the edges, I made sure of that. However, there's no telling if when they're first resized, that one or both edges end up with an artifact, though I suspect this is the case. Doing a bleed won't (always) work because some of these images need to match up when the edges meet, and having a bleed which gets trimmed will cause that to not match up. So I think my choice here is to read, extent, distort, and finally resize, as opposed to read, resize, extent, and distort. I'll try that and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can accomplish tiling images around a circle with `Magick::Image.distort`. Although some trial & error would be expected as you have very localized requirements for your POV project.

#### Repeat Image Along Circle

[ArcDistortion](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#arc) examples apply, just the same, in `Magick++`. Ensure you enable a virtual pixel method, and distort a given image with an 360 degree Arc. I'm using image "pattern:CHECKERBOARD", but you would use "tile:image_source.png".

```cpp
Magick::Image MyArc;
MyArc.read("pattern:CHECKERBOARD");
MyArc.size("600x45");
MyArc.virtualPixelMethod(Magick::WhiteVirtualPixelMethod);
const double arcArgs[1] = {360};
MyArc.distort(Magick::ArcDistortion,1, arcArgs,Magick::MagickTrue);
MyArc.write("out.png");
```

This will give you a repeating image along a circle.

[image: Example arc distortion]

#### Preserver Inner Circle

To control the size of the inner & outer circle. Apply the 3rd & 4th arguments to the distortion method.

```cpp
const double arcArgs[4] = {360,0,200,100};
MyArc.distort(Magick::ArcDistortion,4, arcArgs,Magick::MagickTrue);
```

[image: Example arc distortion around given circle]

#### Custom Image with Pre-Processing

As far as adding whitespace, padding, bleeding, and adjust image repetition. Those will all require pre-processing before arc distortion.

```cpp
Magick::Image SourceImage;
SourceImage.read("me.png");
SourceImage.resize("45x45");
// Add whitespace between repeating image
SourceImage.extent(Magick::Geometry(100,45));

// Resize image to be "long" enough to bend around arc.
SourceImage.size("600x45");
// PrePrecess image to tile horizontally with Edge Virtual Pixel
SourceImage.virtualPixelMethod(Magick::HorizontalTileEdgeVirtualPixelMethod);
const double tileArgs[1] = {0};
SourceImage.distort(Magick::ScaleRotateTranslateDistortion,1,tileArgs,Magick::MagickTrue);

// Distort around circle
SourceImage.virtualPixelMethod(Magick::WhiteVirtualPixelMethod);
const double arcArgs[4] = {360,0,200,100};
SourceImage.distort(Magick::ArcDistortion,4, arcArgs,Magick::MagickTrue);
SourceImage.write("out.png");
```

[image: Arc distortion with custom image frequency]

Just remember a lot if POV issues can be resolved with [fun math](http://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/circle.html).

Comment: Hey thanks for the extensive explanation. If you don't mind, could you explain a few lines to me? Specifically, this last piece of code that works with your image. I understand where you're resizing it to a 45x45 image. The next line, why are you extending it to 100x45? Is that to add the white space in between the images?

Next, when you size it to 600x45, again, why is that?

Comment: Updated answer with additional line comments. Really, the width of "600x45" should be the desired circumference. It should be adjusted to match the point-of-interest in POV, but you can get a starting point by calculating `(bottomRadius * 2 + imageHeight / 2) * PI`

Comment: Thanks! Now I will continue with my next step which it to add some logic to it. Images that are taller than they are wide need to repeat more often where those that are wider than taller need to repeat less. For now I'm doing it manually but I'm hoping eventually to come up with an average set of numbers that will take care of it automatically. I'm thinking working out the proportions and go from there. This part is all about visualization of the image (how it would look like once spun on the POV stick.) Thanks again for your help!